# How to fetch Active Directory Active Users with their email address property c#

Tags: active-directory

How to fetch the active Active Directory Users with their Email Address and  transform the users in my own domain users Model? I tried the code below but it doesn't allow me to fetch Email Address:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com"))
{
    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
    {
        foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
            Console.WriteLine("First Name: " + de.Properties["givenName"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Last Name : " + de.Properties["sn"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("SAM account name   : " + de.Properties["samAccountName"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("User principal name: " + de.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

---

Comment: Your code is not reading the value of `mail` attribute at all, but still you say that email-addresses are not being fetched!

Comment: yes bcz `de.properties` dnt have any email property

Comment: NO, they do have. Try this: `Console.WriteLine("Email Address : " + de.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString());`

Comment: I agree. You've made no attempt to actually get the email address.